# How to forward inexistant email addresses to specific accounts in GMail?

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps, forwarding, email-forwarding

**In short:**
I want to forward all emails going to info@abc.com [this inbox does not exist] to joe@abc.com [this inbox exists].

**The full scenario:**
Up till some time ago I simply owned a domain but not an email inbox for accounts in that domain.  For example although I owned abc.com I did not have email inboxes setup for any email address and yet I still wanted to receive emails that have the abc.com domain.  What I did from within GoDaddy was to set up email forwarding and I could receive emails going to joe@abc.com, info@abc.com, and other nice email addresses into another inbox of my choice like joseph@myweb.com:

[From GoDaddy:]
[image]

It worked like a charm. On my business cards I could print any email address I set up and in reality I would only receive the email in another email inbox.  The only big disadvantage was of course that I couldnt reply back with the same email address.  But that did not matter much at the time.

Now I have made what I thought was going to be an improvement.  I bought **Google Apps** for business and I have set up a single user.  Obviously a single user would have a single inbox.  But I still need to maintain other email addresses.  If for example my single user is joe@abc.com, I still want to receive emails that go to info@abc.com by having them forwarded to joe@abc.com.

One problem, it seems I can't set this up and therefore I'm in a worse-than-before situation with a paid plan!  I can't just pay more and more users in google apps just to have emails forwarded.  Setting a catch-all account is not a solution for me because I don't want all that spam and my account could be blocked due to overload.

I [examined this link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/77182?hl=en), tried some options, but no, I still can't say: Send info@abc.com to joe@abc.com

Can you help me please?

Comment: did you read this link and tried (7th point) ? https://support.google.com/a/answer/175745

Comment: What point 7 in that link is saying is that if an email is sent to A@abc.com but you forward it to Z@abc.com, the To: address will automatically be changed to Z@abc.com even if the email sent originally be the sender specified A@abc.com.  However both the inboxes if A@abc.ocm and Z@abc.com exist.

Answer (score 0):

Last moment before asking for support from Google I found the solution.  It's still not exactly the same but at least I got closer.

1. Go to google admin console
2. Click on the 'Users' icon on the dashboard
3. Select the user that shall receive emails from different email addresses
4. Click on Profile
5. Find the aliases section
6. Add any alias you want

The downside?  In the GoDaddy solution I could forward any email received on an alias to many email addresses.  In this solution, one alias can be linked to only one real email address.  E.g. info@abc.com can be received by only one other real email inbox and not more...

The mistake I was doing is that I was looking for FORWARDING solutions not ALIAS solutions...

;)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the use of Email Aliases (also known as Alternate Emails). Official Google instructions are [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?sjid=18322633349213756876-NA&visit_id=638342829978614578-4207153090&p=CustomFromDenied&rd=1).